# Bash script for rebalancing weighted round robin

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I have written a tool that is used to rebalance weights in a weighted round robin in AWS. I am quite happy with it whereas I would welcome feedback from any Bash programmers.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -g -A set_identifiers

usage() {
  echo "\
Usage: $0 list zones                 # list hosted zones
Usage: $0 -z HOSTEDZONE list names   # list record set names in
                                     # hosted zone with weights and sets
Usage: $0 -z HOSTEDZONE -r RECORDSET -S SETID -a ACTION
  Available actions:
    X   # Configure weight on this set to exactly X
    X%  # Distribute X% of traffic to this set
[+-]X%  # Adjust traffic by +/- X%"

  exit 1
}

indent() {
  sed 's/^/  /'
}

get_opts() {
  [ -z "$*" ] && usage

  while getopts ":z:r:S:a:" opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
      z) hosted_zone_id="$OPTARG" ;;
      r) resource_record_set="$OPTARG" ;;
      S) set_identifier_a="$OPTARG" ;;
      a) action="$OPTARG" ;;
      \?) echo "ERROR: Invalid option -$OPTARG"
          usage ;;
    esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))

  [ -n "$1" ] && command="$1 $2"
}

validate_opts() {
  local f com commands vars var message

  vars=(
    hosted_zone_id
    resource_record_set
    set_identifier_a
    action
  )

  commands=(
    'list zones'
    'list names'
  )

  if [ -n "$command" ] ; then
    f=0 ; for com in "${commands[@]}" ; do
      [ "$command" == "$com" ] && ((f++))
    done

    if ((f==0)) ; then
      echo "Unknown command $command"
      usage
    fi
  fi

  if [ "$command" == "list names" ] ; then
    if [ -z "$hosted_zone_id" ] ; then
      echo "You must set hosted zone ID. Try list zones"
      usage
    fi
  fi

  [ -n "$command" ] && return

  for var in "${vars[@]}" ; do
    if eval '[ -z "$'"$var"'" ]' ; then
      echo "$var is not set"
      usage
    fi
  done

  message="action must be either a number between \
0 and 100, a percentage like 83%, or an increment like \
+5% or -7%"

  if [[ $action =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    if ((action > 100)) ; then
      echo "$message"
      usage
    fi
  elif [[ $action =~ ^[0-9]+%$ ]] ; then
    :
  elif [[ $action =~ ^[+-][0-9]+%$ ]] ; then
    :
  else
    echo "$message"
    usage
  fi
}

list_hosted_zones() {
  aws route53 list-hosted-zones | jq .
}

list_sets_and_weights() {
  aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
    --hosted-zone-id "$hosted_zone_id" \
    --query \
'ResourceRecordSets[?Weight!=`null`]' | jq .
}

get_set_identifiers() {
  local set_id weight

  while IFS=$'\t' read -r set_id weight ; do
    set_identifiers["$set_id"]="$weight"

    if [ "$set_identifier_a" != "$set_id" ] ; then
      set_identifier_b="$set_id"
    fi
  done \
    <<< \
  "$(
    aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
      --output 'text' \
      --hosted-zone-id "$hosted_zone_id" \
      --query \
'ResourceRecordSets[?Name==`'"$resource_record_set"'`].[SetIdentifier, Weight]'
   )"
}

update_weight() {
  local set_id="$1"
  local weight="$2"
  printf "Updating %s to weight %s\n" "$set_id" "$weight"
  aws route53 list-resource-record-sets \
    --hosted-zone-id "$hosted_zone_id" \
    --query \
'ResourceRecordSets[?Name==`'"$resource_record_set"'` && SetIdentifier==`'"$set_id"'`]' | \
\
  jq \
    --arg script "$0" \
    --arg weight "$weight" \
  '
  {
    "Comment": "Update by \($script)",
    "Changes": [
      {
        "Action": "UPSERT",
        "ResourceRecordSet": (.[0] | .Weight = ($weight | tonumber))
      }
    ]
  }
  ' > change-resource-record-sets.json

  printf "Applying change record set:\n"
  jq . change-resource-record-sets.json | indent

  printf "Running aws route53 change-resource-record-sets:\n"
  aws route53 change-resource-record-sets \
    --hosted-zone-id "$hosted_zone_id" \
    --change-batch 'file://change-resource-record-sets.json'
}

set_absolute() {
  printf "Setting %s to absolute weight %s\n" "$set_identifier_a" "$action"
  update_weight "$set_identifier_a" "$action"
}

set_percent() {
  printf "Setting %s to %s\n" "$set_identifier_a" "$action"

  local a b s

  a="${action//%/}"
  ((b = 100 - a))

  update_weight "$set_identifier_a" "$a"
  update_weight "$set_identifier_b" "$b"
}

convert_to_percent() {
  printf "Recomputing weights on a 0 to 100 scale\n"

  local t ap bp s a b

  a="${set_identifiers["$set_identifier_a"]}"
  b="${set_identifiers["$set_identifier_b"]}"

  ((t = a + b))
  ((ap = a * 100/t))
  ((bp = b * 100/t))

  set_identifiers["$set_identifier_a"]="$ap"
  set_identifiers["$set_identifier_b"]="$bp"

  printf "  Got %s for %s\n" "$ap" "$set_identifier_a"
  printf "  Got %s for %s\n" "$bp" "$set_identifier_b"
}

adjust_by_percent() {
  printf "Adjusting %s by %s\n" "$set_identifier_a" "$action"

  local op po s n

  convert_to_percent

  op="${action//%/}"                # e.g. +5
  po="$(sed 'y/+-/-+/' <<< "$op")"  #   => -5

  for s in "${!set_identifiers[@]}" ; do
    n="${set_identifiers["$s"]}"

    if [ "$s" == "$set_identifier_a" ] ; then
      eval "((n = n $op))"
    else
      eval "((n = n $po))"
    fi

    ((n > 100)) && n=100
    ((n < 0))   && n=0

    update_weight "$s" "$n"
  done
}

cleanup() {
  rm -f change-resource-record-sets.json
}

main() {
  get_opts "$@"
  validate_opts

  case "$command" in
    "list zones")
      list_hosted_zones
      exit 0
      ;;
    "list names")
      list_sets_and_weights
      exit 0
      ;;
  esac

  if [[ $action =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    set_absolute ; cleanup ; exit 0
  fi

  get_set_identifiers

  if [[ $action =~ ^[0-9]+%$ ]] ; then
    set_percent
  elif [[ $action =~ ^[+-][0-9]+%$ ]] ; then
    adjust_by_percent
  fi

  cleanup
}

if [ "$0" == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ] ; then
  main "$@"
fi

# vim: set ft=sh:
```